# Помогите разобраться как найти решение к задаче с олимпиады

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада

Несколько дней пытаюсь найти решение к ниже описанной задачи

**Орехи**

Сегодня Сёма и Юра посетили закрытие одной олимпиады. На праздничных столах стояли n тарелок с орехами. В i-ой тарелке находится ai орехов.

За одну минуту Сёма может выбрать некоторые тарелки и некоторое число x, после чего с каждой выбранной тарелки забрать ровно x орехов (конечно, каждая выбранная тарелка должна иметь хотя бы x орешков).

Определите, за какое наименьшее количество минут все орешки могут оказаться в кармане Сёмы.

*Входные данные*
Первая строка содержит одно целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 50) - количество тарелок с орешками.

Вторая строка содержит n целых чисел a1, a2, ..., an (1 ≤ ai ≤ 50) - количество орешков в i-ой тарелке.

*Выходные данные*
Выведите единственное число - искомое минимальное количество минут.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на задачу: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/8769
Здесь можно проверить и решения.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то по крайней мере подскажет в какую сторону двигаться, чтобы найти алгоритм решения. Спасибо.

Comment: Я не понял про Юру. Он останется без орехов?

Comment: "в какую сторону двигаться" - Предположим у нас 7 тарелок с количеством орехов 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. Как забрать все орехи за наименьшее количество ходов?

Comment: @Igor Довольно-таки неочевидный вопрос. Можно за 3 хода, сильно подозреваю, что это минимум, но обосновать затрудняюсь.

Comment: Вам понятно, как для Ваших данных получается ответ 2?

Comment: @Igor Да. 11 - 4 == 7 и 7 - 7 == 0

Comment: Написано же - за одну минуту он все это сможет сделать.

Answer (score 0):

> 11 - 4 == 7 и 7 - 7 == 0

Мне не ясно, что значат эти вычисления. Но думаю, что они неправильные :).

Надо отсортировать уникальные количества орехов. Потом взять значение из середины этого отсортированного массива и вычесть его из себя и всех значений больше него. Отбросить ноль. Снова отсортировать. И так далее.

Comment: Интереса для проверил ваше решение - больше половины не проходит (я правильно понял вашу идею? http://vpaste.net/ZfVla)

Comment: Я имел в виду, что решение состоит из двух шагов:
1. Мы от 11 вычитаем 4 и у нас остается три тарелки с семью орехами
2. Мы с каждой тарелки забираем 7 орехов

Answer (score 0):

примерное решение:
1) отсоритировать, сгруппировать все тарелки по количеству
2) вычитать прямоугольниками из той фигуры что вышла в п.1
3) для каждого возможного нового шага оценивать эффективность:
- смотреть сколько орехов можно забрать за такой шаг
- если тарелка после вычитания группируется с другой тарелкой - в эффективность добавлять полное количество тарелки, а не только вычитаемое
- при подсчете эффективности не обращать внимание на количество тарелок в "группе"